# Euler's formula reversed: How does $1.609+1.025i$ become $1.908e^{i32.5^{\circ}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Recently I saw in a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_h49ilnTmW4&t=508s) where one of the examples was $$e^{i50^{\circ}} + e^{i15^{\circ}} = 1.609+1.025i = 1.908e^{i32.5^{\circ}}$$ My question is: how did he get from $$1.609+1.025i$$ to $$1.908e^{i32.5^{\circ}}$$

Comment: Recall that $x+iy=re^{i\theta}$ for $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ and $\theta = \arctan (y/x)$. Note: in that case $\arctan$ works properly because $z$ is in the first quadrant.

Comment: Refer also to the following  [LINK](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $A,B\in \Bbb R$ and $A, B$ are not both $0$ then the complex number $$Z=A+iB=R(A'+iB')=R(\cos t +i\sin t)=Re^{it}$$ where $R=\sqrt {A^2+B^2},$

and $A'=A/R$  and $B'=B/R,$

and $t$ is any  angle such that $\cos t=A'$ and $\sin t=B'.$

Geometrically we can interpret $Z =A+iB$  as the point $(A,B)$ in the plane $\Bbb R^2$. Then $R$ is the Euclidean distance from $Z=(A,B)$ to the origin $O=(0,0),$ and  $t$ is the angle between the line-segment $ZO$ and the half-axis $[0,\infty)\times \{0\},$ with $t>0$ if $B>0$ and $t<0$ if $B<0.$... And with $t=0$ if $A>0=B,$ while $t=-\pi$ if $A<0=B.$

Of course we can change $t$ to $t+2n\pi$ for any integer $n$ without affecting $Z.$

It is usually preferable to work in radians in pure maths  instead of degrees. A radian is not even a  "unit" since $\pi$ radians is the same thing as the number $\pi.$

Answer (score 2):

since the two complex numbers have the same magnitude, that being $1,$ we get a perfect rhombus with the four numbers  $0, e^{i 15^\circ}, e^{i 50^\circ}$ and the sum you are asked about. The sum is along the angle bisector and must be a multiple of $e^{i 32.5^\circ}$ since $(50+15)/2= 65/2 = 32.5$

Neither the short diagonal nor the long diagonal of the rhombus is particularly nice as far as magnitude. However, we can find the long diagonal with the Law of Cosines, 
$$ c^2 = 1 + 1 - 2 \cos 145^\circ \approx 1 + 1 + 2 \cdot 0.819152044 \approx 3.638304089, $$
so the magnitude is
$$ c \approx 1.907433902 $$

Comment: That's a nice geometrical interpretation, given that complex numbers behave as vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$.